# Nest Wifi - What to look for to make sure your current modem is compatible with a Nest Wifi device?

Tags: wifi, nest

I'm about to pull the trigger on buying a Nest Wifi https://store.google.com/ca/product/nest_wifi.

So before I spend 200$ on that... how can I verify that my current modem can handle the Nest Wifi?

Are the cables from the modem to the router universal?

Comment: what modem are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cable modem has an open ethernet port you will be good to go. The nest wifi becomes the router/mesh network so if you have a modem/router combo you may need to put it in bridge mode.

Comment: Also, if your cable modem is a modem + wifi router combo, it is possible to just connect the nest wifi to one of the ethernet ports and have it work, but remember to turn off the wifi feature in the modem. 
You can either put it in bridge mode or just leave it as is, and the nest wifi should get an IP address via the modem's dhcp service and then the nest will run its own dhcp in its subnet. I got my google wifi mesh working that way. All i had to do was turn off the modem's wifi feature and it actually had a physical switch on the modem to do that.